# Swift PDFKit PDFAnnotationSquare deprecated in macOS 10.12

Tags: swift, pdf, warnings, macos-sierra

Using PDFAnnotationSquare in macOS 10.12 gives me this warning:

```
PDFAnnotationSquare was deprecated in OS X 10.12: Use the PDFAnnotation class directly, setting properties via kPDFAnnotationKey_* keys using method [setValue:forAnnotationKey:]
```

How can "use PDFAnnotation class directly"?

Note: PDFKit presents some unexpected behaviour under macOS 10.12, so I hope that removing all the warning like this can bring the usual behaviour back. For instance the documentView do not redraw when I add new notes.